# How does this find command using "find ... -exec sh -c '...' sh {} +" work?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, find

@StephaneChazelas posted the following solution to this Q&A: [Having some trouble using “find -exec {} +”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79054/having-some-trouble-using-find-exec).

```
$ find . -iname "*.extension" -exec sh -c '
  exec <command> "$@" <additional parameters>' sh {} +
```

What exactly is going on here? Specifically what does the last `sh {}` do? It seems as though it's just there to pacify find's `-exec` command so that it has something to do, a NOOP.

I could just as easily put `echo {}` there and it appears to work just fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
find ... -exec cmd {} +
```

`find` will find a number of files based on the criteria in `...` and run `cmd` with that list of file paths as arguments, as many as possible without surpassing the limit on the size of the arguments to a command.

If needed it may split the list of files and call `cmd` several times.  For instance, it may end up calling:

```
cmd ./file1 ./file2 ... ./file3000
cmd ./file3001 ./file3002 ... ./file4321
```

A limitation with that is that `{}` has to be last. You can't for instance write:

```
find ... -exec cmd {} other args +
```

like you could with `';'` instead of `'+'`.

You can write:

```
find ... -exec echo foo {} +
```

but not:

```
find ... -exec echo {} foo +
```

So, if you do need to add some extra arguments to `cmd` after the list of files, you have to resort to calling a shell.  (Other reasons why you'd need to call a shell would be any time you need to use a shell feature like redirections, pipes, some string expansions....)

In `sh -c 'inline-script' x a b c`, for the `inline-script`, `$0` is `x`, `$1` is `a`, `$2` is `b`... so `"$@"` is the list of those 3 arguments: a, b and c. So in:

```
find ... -exec sh -c 'cmd "$@" other arg' find-sh {} +
```

For the *inline script*, `$0` (which is used for instance when displaying error messages) is set to `find-sh` and `"$@"` is the list of files (what `find` expands `{}` to).

By using the `exec` special builtin of the shell:

```
find ... -exec sh -c 'exec cmd "$@" other arg' find-sh {} +
```

We tell the shell not to fork an extra process to run `cmd`, but instead to run it in the same process (replacing the running shell process with that command).  Some shells like `zsh` and some implementations of `ksh` do that implicitly for the last command in an inline script (also `bash` when there's only one command in the inline script like here).

Comment: Could you use a subshell instead  of exec there? `-exec sh -c '(cmd1; cmd2;)' find-sh {} +`?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the `find-sh {}` are arguments to the sh -c '...' command, right?

Comment: @slm, `find` will call `/bin/sh` with as arguments `("sh", "-c", "...", "find-sh", "./file1", "./file2"...). And inside `...`, that maps (the shells maps that) to `$0` being `"find-sh"`, and the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`... which you could say are the arguments to the _inline script_) being `./file1`, `./file2`.