# Converting `for file in` to `find` so that my script can apply recursively

Tags: debian, shell-script, find, recursive, for

I have this idea of running a bash script to check some conditions and using `ffmpeg` to convert all the videos in my directory from any format to `.mkv` and it is working great!

The thing is, I did not know that a `for file in` loop does not work recursively (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638874/how-to-loop-through-a-directory-recursively)

But I barely understand "piping" and am looking forward to seeing an example and clearing some uncertainties.

I have this scenario in mind that I think would help me a lot to understand.

Suppose I have this bash script snippet:

```
for file in *.mkv *avi *mp4 *flv *ogg *mov; do
target="${file%.*}.mkv"
    ffmpeg -i "$file" "$target" && rm -rf "$file"
done
```

What it does is, for the current directory, search for any `*.mkv *avi *mp4 *flv *ogg *mov` then declare the output to have its extension to be `.mkv` then afterwards delete the original file, then the output should be saved to the very same folder the original video is in.

1. How can I convert this to run recursively? if I use `find`, where to declare the variable `$file`? And where should you declare `$target`? Are all `find` just really one-liners? I really need to pass the file to a variable `$file`, because I will still need to run the condition check.
2. And, assuming that (1) is successful, how to make sure that the requirement "then the output should be save to the very same folder the original video is in" is satisfied?

Comment: Some shells have a [`**` globing operator](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62660/the-result-of-ls-ls-and-ls) to search for files recursively. Its not portable but it plays nice with the for-loop syntax.

Comment: I ended up turning the bunch of comments I wrote into an answer of its own, addressing your minor questions like how to declare shell vars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got this code:

> ```
> for file in *.mkv *avi *mp4 *flv *ogg *mov; do
> target="${file%.*}.mkv"
>     ffmpeg -i "$file" "$target" && rm -rf "$file"
> done
> ```

which runs in the current directory. To turn it into a recursive process you have a couple of choices. The easiest (IMO) is to use `find` as you suggested. The syntax for `find` is very "un-UNIX-like" but the principle here is that each argument can be applied with AND or OR conditions. Here, we're going to say "*If this-filename matches OR that-filename matches Then print-it*". The filename patterns are quoted so that the shell can't get hold of them (remember that the shell is responsible for expanding all unquoted patterns, so if you had an unquoted pattern of `*.mp4` and you had `janeeyre.mp4` in your current directory, the shell would replace `*.mp4` with the match, and `find` would see `-name janeeyre.mp4` instead of your desired `-name *.mp4`; it gets worse if `*.mp4` matches multiple names...). The brackets are prefixed with `\` also to keep the shell from trying to action them as subshell markers (we could quote the brackets instead, if preferred: `'('`).

```
find . \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*avi' -o -name '*mp4' -o -name '*flv' -o -name '*ogg' -o -name '*mov' \) -print
```

The output of this needs to be fed into the input of a `while` loop that processes each file in turn:

```
while IFS= read file    ## IFS= prevents "read" stripping whitespace
do
    target="${file%.*}.mkv"
    ffmpeg -i "$file" "$target" && rm -rf "$file"
done
```

Now all that's left is to join the two parts together with a pipe `|` so that the output of the `find` becomes the input of the `while` loop.

While you're testing this code I'd recommend you prefix both `ffmpeg` and `rm` with `echo` so you can see what *would* be executed - and with what paths.

Here is the final result, including the `echo` statements I recommend for testing:

```
find . \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*avi' -o -name '*mp4' -o -name '*flv' -o -name '*ogg' -o -name '*mov' \) -print |
    while IFS= read file    ## IFS= prevents "read" stripping whitespace
        do
            target="${file%.*}.mkv"
            echo ffmpeg -i "$file" "$target" && echo rm -rf "$file"
        done
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation. (1) `The filename patterns are quoted so that the shell can't get hold of them` sorry, what does this mean? aren't they supposed to be hold? (2) how did you pipe `-print` with `IFS= read file`, can you show me how to pipe them?

Comment: This will fail if filename contain newline.

Comment: The shell expands stuff first, and this can have unexpected consequences.Try `echo *` in an empty directory. Then try it in a non empty directory. The former prints `*` and the latter replaces the star with a list of files. The same thing occurs with `find`.

Comment: @cuonglm I'm aware of that, thanks. At this level I'm not bothered.

Comment: @cuonglm thanks too. but yes, I'm just trying to learn the basics, but I will keep that in mind. I think that's where `xargs` comes in?

Comment: @TheWolf `xargs` can be a minefield. Take great care with that one.

Comment: @TheWolf: If `xargs` and `find` without `-0` option, you still have trouble. Let `find` does all the work with `-exec` is better solution.

Comment: Using `find -print0` with `IFS= read -r -d '' file` will also handle the newline case (and the backslash-escape-literals case, and otherwise all the situations where this code is broken as given).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're welcome to improve it. I wanted something simple enough that it could be understood by a beginner. If we start using `-print0` and the other professional accoutrements you'll get more solid code, certainly, but more complexity that needs to be explained.

Comment: @roaima, I've made an effort to make improvements here (awaiting moderation at the moment). Let me know if the explanation on any point needs further expansion.

Comment: Better to learn safe ways of scripting from the start, rather than learning ways that break on odd filenames.  (Up to a point, anyway.  IFS= read ... is pretty good, and suggested by http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 6):

With POSIX find:

```
find . \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*avi' -o -name '*mp4' -o -name '*flv' -o \
          -name '*ogg' -o -name '*mov' \) -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    target="${file%.*}.mkv"
    echo ffmpeg -i "$file" "$target"
  done' sh {} +
```

Replace `echo` with whatever command you want to use.

If you have GNU find or BSD find, you can use `-regex`:

```
find . -regex '.*\.\(mkv\|avi\|mp4\|flv\|ogg\|mov\)'
```

Comment: sorry, but I cannot follow how adding `find . \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*avi' -o -name '*mp4' -o -name '*flv' -o \
          -name '*ogg' -o -name '*mov' \) -exec sh -c '` at the top of the snippet would be piped down `file`. and what does `sh {} +` ? Thanks!

Comment: Not portable but shorter `find . -regex '.*\.\(mkv\|avi\|mp4\|flv\|ogg\|mov\)'`

Comment: @TheWolf: I invite you to read http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93324/38906

Answer (score 2):

Example snippet without piping (assumes you are giving the path as argument):

```
#!/bin/bash

backup_dir=/backup/

OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

files="$(find "$1" -type f -name '*.mkv' -or -name '*.avi' -or -name '*.mp4' -or -name '*.ogg' -or -name '*.mov' -or -name '*.flv')"

for f in $files; do
    # get path
    d="${f%/*}"
    # get filename
    b="$(basename "$f")"
    ttarget="${b%.*}.mkv"

    # this is your final target
    target="$d/$ttarget"
    echo $target
    # mv $f "$backup_dir" 
done

IFS="$OIFS"
```

The shell reads the `IFS` variable, which is set to (`space`, `tab`, `newline`) by default. Then it looks at each character in the output of `find`. So if it finds `space` it thinks it is end of the filename (file containing spaces for example "Sin City.avi" ill be treated as two files "Sin" and "City.avi"). So with IFS=$'\n' we are telling to split the input on `newlines`. And finally we restore old (default) `IFS` which is saved in `$OIFS` variable.
Or as suggested in comments may be better approach could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

backup_dir=/backup/

find "$1" -type f \( -name '*.mkv' -or -name '*.avi' -or -name '*.mp4' -or -name '*.ogg' -or -name '*.mov' -or -name '*.flv' \) -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f
do
    # get path
    d="${f%/*}"
    # get filename
    b="$(basename "$f")"
    ttarget="${b%.*}.mkv"

    # this is your final target
    target="$d/$ttarget"
    echo $target
    # mv $f "$backup_dir"
done
```

Comment: this seems handy, but actually I did not understand the declaration of vars `OIFS` and `IFS` at the start and bottom of the script. and if I understand correctly, the path is declared at var `$1`? and the `backup_dir` is just merely a backup for debugging right?

Comment: IFS is a variable that defines what your field separator value is going to be.  The default IFS is usually "whitespace".  So spaces, tabs, newlines, etc, will all be recognized as "field separators". Since some movies and songs may be named with spaces in them, this script is saying ignore spaces and tables, and use newlines as the separator.  This way, instead or "Terminator 2.mp4" being recognized as 2 movies, "Terminator" and "2.mp4", it's seen as 1 movie "Terminator 2.mp4".   Since IFS was saved as OIFS, the end of the script sets that back as the default.

Comment: Another way to do this is to put your code in a shell function that does `local IFS=`, so IFS is empty just for the context of your function, and doesn't need to be saved/restored.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Unix :)

To answer some of your minor questions that answers to the main question didn't cover:

Shell scripting certainly has some rough edges, since a lot of things break on file names with spaces. And almost everything breaks on filenames with newlines (fortunately, nobody makes those on purpose).  Filenames containing glob characters like `[`, `]`, and `*` are sometimes a problem, too. Sometimes it's just not worth writing hard-to-read shell code up to the standards of [wooledge's BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), for your own use, or for a one-off where you know your filenames aren't weird.

> where to declare the variable:

Shell variables don't need to be declared.  In bash, you can `shopt -o nounset` to make it an error to reference and unSET variable, but that's not quite the same thing as undeclared.  Unsetting a variable can be useful.  In a shell function, it is good practice to declare all your temporaries with `local foo bar baz;`, so you don't litter the shell environment with variables, or worse, step on the caller's variable of the same name.

> I barely understand "piping".

When working with the shell, a lot of data passing happens by printing the data to stdout.  Pipes send that data to another program, which reads it on stdin (and usually prints something on stdout).  You can capture output into shell variables using command substitution, `$()`. e.g. `for i in $( locate foo | grep bar );do echo "$i"; done`. (this will break on filenames with spaces in them, like a lot of shell code if you aren't careful. Use `read` if you want to write scripts that are reliable.)  `locate` prints, `grep` reads and prints, and the shell reads the output of `grep`.  (The shell gets its hands on the output of `grep` by starting grep with its output connected to the input side of a pipe which the shell created.  The shell reads the output side of the pipe.)

A pipe is just a way for programs to work like they're writing to a file, but actually they're writing into a small buffer.  A process reading from a pipe will have its `read(2)` system call return when there's data available, which only happens when something writes to the other end of the pipe.

The shell's `|`, `$()`, and some other syntax elements are how you tell the shell how to set up the plumbing connecting programs to each other, and to the shell.

It's easy to learn bad idioms for shell programming, because a lot of the obvious things and old ways of doing things have hidden pitfalls which break on odd filenames.  See for example http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001.

Better to learn safe ways of scripting from the start, rather than learning ways that break on odd filenames, as long as they're not too clunky to type. :)

A lot of GNU utils have a -0 option, to use ASCII NUL (the 0 byte, can't be present in filenames or text) as a record separator.  This lets you pipe data between `find` and `sort`, for example, without any possibility of having one "line" of find output turned into multiple lines of sort input.  This ends up not being super useful when you want to get the data into a shell variable, because bash doesn't have a way to read `\0`-delimited lines.  (I don't think that's a valid value for IFS.)

Anyway, avoiding having the shell treat data as code is the reason to always double-quote everything you can, unless you really WANT word-splitting.  If you ever want to make your brain hurt looking at complex shell code, just look at the bash-completion code.  (It handles the programmable completion that does clever things like completing `ls --colo => --color`, or only completing *.zip files for unzip.)  `set -x` and hit tab :P.  (set +x to turn off execution tracing.)

re: your for loop:
with `*.mkv` as one of your patterns, you're going to have source = dest for those input files.  `ffmpeg` will prompt you to overwrite the output file for each one.

Also, do you really need to transcode the audio?  `-c:a copy` might be a good idea.  Video bitrate is usually a bigger deal.  And you might want to use `-preset slow` (or `slower`, or even `veryslow`) to get more quality per bitrate, at the cost of more CPU usage.  There's also `-crf 20` (default 23).  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264.  You hopefully already knew this, and left it out because it wasn't relevant to the bash scripting, but just in case... :P  `-c:v libx264` is the default when outputting to mkv, so that's good.