# replace `while` with more suitable function so looping would wait for each process to end

Tags: centos, process, ffmpeg

I have a bash script that look out for files recursively under multi-sub folders, then use `ffmpeg` to each file. at debug, it works great if i use `echo ffmpeg` but the thing is, at real work where it actually needs to use `ffmpeg` and wait for half an hour to finish for each video, the bash script cannot successfully run the `ffmpeg` to each file

My snippet is below:

```
find * \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*avi' -o -name '*mp4' -o -name '*flv' -o -name '*ogg' -o -name '*mov' ! -name '*-[900p].mkv' \) -print |
while IFS= read file    ## IFS= prevents "read" stripping whitespace
do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" "$target" && rm -rf "$file"
done
```

the thing is, because ffmpeg takes too long to respond, and `while` would just keep listing and executing. So I'm hoping what can I do to make sure loop would be process only after the `done` has ended?

Can somebody please help? Thanks!

Geez, I do not know why it was tagged as possible duplicate with another question of mine: [Converting `for file in` to `find` so that my script can apply recursively](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196633/converting-for-file-in-to-find-so-that-my-script-can-apply-recursively)

I am asking for a loop action that would allow my bash script to wait for each function inside the loop to finish before iterating to the next object. It is very far from asking how to `find` files recursively. Thanks!

Comment: @Costas very far from the topic of mine. Hoped I expressed my problem and scenario well.

Comment: Do you mean you would like `find` to complete before the first call to `ffmpeg` happens? As it is, the loop *will* wait for `ffmpeg` to complete before processing the next file, so it's not very clear what you are asking.

Comment: @dhag yeah! seems like that's the idea and feasible.

Comment: Why are you using `find *` (asterisk) ? Why do you need the `-r` with `rm`  to remove a file ? And `while..read` is the worst option... Try something like: `find . \( -name '*avi' -o -name .... \) -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" "${0%.*}.mkv" && rm -f "$0"' {} \;`

Comment: @don_crissti you're rught, i need to cleanup my code. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of piping find into the loop, you could go through an
intermediate file. That will ensure that the finding step and the
looping step happen in sequence, with no overlap. Something like the
following (I altered your expression for brevity):

```
find \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*avi' \) >files
<files while IFS= read file
do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" "$target" && rm -f "$file"
done
```

Note that this still isn't completely safe; using `find -exec` would be simpler if your requirements didn't include running `find` strictly before the first call to `ffmpeg`. With this requirement, using `find -print0` along with xargs or GNU parallel could do the job.

Comment: I'm super-unsure this is what you are asking... Don't hesitate to comment if I'm answering the wrong question.

Comment: yes! I just want to make sure they happen in sequence and do not overlap, exactly as you said. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason the code is failing to run properly is the mismatch of AND and OR groups in the initial `find` command:

```
find * \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*avi' -o -name '*mp4' -o -name '*flv' -o -name '*ogg' -o -name '*mov' ! -name '*-[900p-by-ZiriusPH].mkv' \) -print
```

The binding for the parameters is to print the files matched for

- Name *.mkv
- OR Name *.avi
- OR Name *mp4
- OR Name *flv
- OR Name *.ogg
- OR Name *.ogg
- OR ( Name *.mov AND Name NOT *-[900p-by-ZiriusPH].mkv )

The last condition will be true for many files, which I suspect is not what you wanted. If you move the AND NOT condition outside the bracketed OR conditions you'll find it works as you expected.

```
find * \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*avi' -o -name '*mp4' -o -name '*flv' -o -name '*ogg' -o -name '*mov' \) ! -name '*-[900p-by-ZiriusPH].mkv' -print
```