# xargs repl_str doesn't expand second placeholder

Tags: shell, find, xargs, command-substitution

I would like to rename some files and exclude others into a directory. I tried

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name 000-default.conf ! -name default-ssl.conf -print0 |
xargs -0 -I {} sudo mv -- {} $(echo {} | sed 's/local.conf/local.example.com.conf/')
```

but it wouldn't work.

I think `mv` command's second argument doesn't expand correctly.

Comment: What makes you think that?  What happens when you run that command?  Please provide the output, and preferably a simplified test case.

Answer (score 2):

The `$(...)` part is being evaluated by the shell before xargs is even called.
What you might try is something like:

```
xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'mv {} $(echo {} | sed "s/local.conf/local.example.com.conf/")'
```

You can avoid the sed with

```
xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'f="{}"; mv "{}" "${f/local.conf/local.example.com.conf}"'
```

See also the `rename` command if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write it without the `xargs`, something like

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name 000-default.conf ! -name default-ssl.conf -exec sh -c '
sudo mv -- "$0" "$(echo "$0" | sed "s/local.conf/local.example.com.conf/")"
```

' {} \;

See [How does this find command using "find ... -exec sh -c '...' sh {} +" work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93324/how-does-this-find-command-using-find-exec-sh-c-sh-work) for more details.