# Recursively delete empty directories with a dotfile / directory exclusion?

Tags: linux, find

How do I recursively delete all directories which do not contain any files and make an exclusion of hidden directories?

A lot of the directories that I wish to delete contain hidden directories (dot directories) with files inside them, I do not want these directories.

However, any directories with actually visible files in them - I wish to keep.

Any suggestions?

***Example (I wish to delete)***

```
v@localhost:~/test$ ls -al
total 20
drwxrwxr-x   3 v v  4096 Oct 28 04:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 255 v v 12288 Oct 28 04:38 ..
drwxrwxr-x   4 v v  4096 Oct 28 04:31 .hidden
```

***Example (I wish to keep)***

```
v@localhost:~/google.com$ ls -al
total 348
drwxrwxr-x   6 v v   4096 Oct 28 04:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 255 v v  12288 Oct 28 04:38 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v     54 Oct 28 04:39 BCF9360BE20A13B7DA407BF12AF28650.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v    254 Oct 28 04:39 crossdomain.xml
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v   1150 Oct 28 04:39 favicon.ico
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v    234 Oct 28 04:39 .htaccess
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v     23 Oct 28 04:39 index.html
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v    418 Oct 28 04:39 index.php
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v  19935 Oct 28 04:39 license.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v 110249 Oct 28 04:39 php_errors.log
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v   7344 Oct 28 04:39 readme.html
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v   5456 Oct 28 04:39 wp-activate.php
drwxrwxr-x   9 v v   4096 Oct 28 04:39 wp-admin
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v    364 Oct 28 04:39 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v   1477 Oct 28 04:39 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v   3376 Oct 28 04:39 wp-config-local.php
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v   5219 Oct 28 04:39 wp-config.php
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v   2853 Oct 28 04:39 wp-config-sample.php
drwxrwxr-x   7 v v   4096 Oct 28 04:39 wp-content
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v   3286 Oct 28 04:39 wp-cron.php
drwxrwxr-x  17 v v  12288 Oct 28 04:39 wp-includes
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v   2382 Oct 28 04:39 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v   3353 Oct 28 04:39 wp-load.php
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v  34057 Oct 28 04:39 wp-login.php
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v   7993 Oct 28 04:39 wp-mail.php
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v  13920 Oct 28 04:39 wp-settings.php
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v  29890 Oct 28 04:39 wp-signup.php
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v   4035 Oct 28 04:39 wp-trackback.php
-rw-rw-r--   1 v v   3064 Oct 28 04:39 xmlrpc.php
```

Comment: I doubt you want to delete . or ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all empty directories in a subtree?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8430/how-to-remove-all-empty-directories-in-a-subtree)

Comment: The proposed duplicate answers how to (blindly) delete subdirectories, while this question wants to exclude certain directories from deletion -- not a duplicate, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

It gets a little complicated, but you could chain together some `find` tests, namely:

- start at the desired directory (`/path/to/dir`)
- start from the bottom up (`-depth`), so that you empty out candidate directories before considering their parent directories
- consider only directories (`-type d`)
- for each of the above matches (one at a time), execute a bash shell that:

  - *sets* the nullglob shell option ensure that the dotglob shell option is *unset*
  - uses the `$1/*` shell glob to set the positional parameters to the number of matching files (and/or directories) in the matched directory -- noting that unsetting dotglob tells bash to *not* count dot-files (or dot-directories) in the expansion, and that the nullglob option will let the glob expand to *nothing* if there are no matches at all.
  - if the number of resulting files/directories is zero, return "success"
- for any directories that passed the above test, execute `rm -r` on them, as many as will fit in an `rm` command at a time (`+`).

Summing up:

```
find /path/to/dir -depth -type d \
  -exec bash -c \
     'shopt -s nullglob; shopt -u dotglob; set -- $1/*; test "$#" -eq 0' find-sh {} \; \
  -exec rm -r {} +
```

Hat-tip to [Stéphane's find/exec answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93331/117549) for providing a nice baseline for this answer to start from.

To create a test-bed:

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
mkdir dir{1..3}
touch dir1/.hidden
touch dir2/foo
touch dir3/bar
```

Answer (score 0):

`rmdir` won't remove a non-empty directory so you can do:

```
find . -type d \! -name '.*' -depth -exec rmdir -v --ignore-fail-on-non-empty {} \;
```

(where `--ignore-fail-on-non-empty` is just about error messages...)