# move files up a level preppending folder-name to file-name?

Tags: bash, text-processing, find

Test environment:

- make directories from `0` to `9` and fill them with files from `a` to `z`

  ```
  $ mkdir {0..9} && touch {0..9}/{a..z}
  ```
- Result of `find`:

  ```
  $ find -type f
  ./0/a
  ./0/b

  ...

  ./9/y
  ./9/z
  ```

How can I transform the output so that it looks like this:

```
./0a    
./0b

...

./9y
./9z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With POSIX tools,

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do dirn="${f%/*}"; mv -- "$f" "$dirn${f##*/}"; done' sh {} +
```

`find` invokes a shell and executes the for loop for each file.

- `dirn="${f%/*}"` gets the parent directory name by excluding all that is after (and including) the last slash in the file name.
- `${f##*/}` gets the filename without the path by excluding all that is before (and including) the last slash in the file name.

Those two shell constructs do the same as [`dirname`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html) and [`basename`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html), so an equivalent form of the command is

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f; do mv -- "$f" "$(dirname "$f")$(basename "$f")"; done' sh {} +
```

, although this one should be slower as it needs to spawn two extra processes for each file.

If you do not need to descend into more than a single directory, such as your example shows, a simple shell loop does it:

```
for f in */*; do dirn="${f%/*}"; echo mv -- "$f" "$dirn${f##*/}"; done
```

Comment: The only part that I couldn't understand (and can't find info on man pages) from the first command is ```sh {} +``` at the end

Comment: @benaiu Have a look at [How does “find … -exec sh -c '…' sh {} +” work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93324). Also, you may want to clarify in your question if you want to move the files up. I imagine so since you have accept this answer, and that's what I thought when I read the original title, but the question was indeed ambiguous and has been edited.

Answer (score 2):

With Perl's standalone `rename` command:

```
rename -n 's|/||' */*
```

If everything looks fine, remove `-n` and then remove remaining empty directories.

```
rmdir {0..9}
```