# How to get the specfied output format via sh -c 'grep ...' with find -exec commands

Tags: shell, find

We want to grep the corresponding files that including some fixed strings, and then output those files just only in ls -l format. 
For example: 
A) the following method with multiple -exec output both the grep and ls -l.

```
# 
# 
# find /usr/bin -type f -exec grep -Eil '#\!\/usr\/bin\/csh' {} \; -exec ls -l  {} \; >scripts_csh_list 2>&1
# 
# 
# 
# cat scripts_csh_list      
/usr/bin/which
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin            1191 Sep 06 2007  /usr/bin/which
#  
#
```

B) But we want to the better method output only with ls -l ... , and then we failed via sh -c 'grep ... {}' 
Notes: all the following different combined  commands for the find -exec ... output the same failed result.

```
#                                                                                                                
# 
# find /usr/bin -type f -exec sh -c 'grep -Eil '\/usr\/bin\/csh' {} && ls -ltr  {}' \; >scripts_csh_list 2>&1t
#  
# 
# tail -6 scripts_csh_list
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
# 
# 
# 
# find /usr/bin -type f -exec sh -c ' grep -Eil '\/usr\/bin\/csh' {} '  \; >scripts_csh_list 2>&1  
# 
# 
# tail -6 scripts_csh_list                                                                         
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
# 
# 
# find /usr/bin -type f -exec sh -c ' grep -Eil '\/usr\/bin\/csh' "{}" '  \; >scripts_csh_list 2>&1  
# 
# 
# tail -6 scripts_csh_list                                                                         
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
# 
# 
# 
# find /usr/bin -type f -exec sh -c " grep -Eil '\/usr\/bin\/csh' {} "  \; >scripts_csh_list 2>&1  
# 
# 
# tail -6 scripts_csh_list                                                                         
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
# 
# 
# 
# find /usr/bin -type f -exec sh -c " grep -Eil '\/usr\/bin\/csh' {} "  \; >scripts_csh_list 2>&1  
# 
# 
# tail -6 scripts_csh_list                                                                         
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
grep: 0652-033 Cannot open {}.
# 
#
```

Comment: If you don't want `grep` to output anything, why are you using `-l`? Why not use `-q`?

Comment: so, hold on, what's the goal there? If `-exec grep ... \;` works, why change it to `-exec sh -c 'grep ...' \;`? Especially when `exec grep \; -exec ls \;` pretty much does the same thing as `-exec sh -c 'grep && ls' \;`, i.e. run `ls` only if grep succeeds

Comment: now, the error there looks odd, but it seems to me that your `find` is one of those that doesn't expand `{}` embedded in other strings. Which is a good thing, as it's a very error-prone way to do anything. Pass the filename as an argument to the `-exec sh -c ... ` script

Comment: you may want to see e.g. [How does this find command using "find ... -exec sh -c '...' sh {} +" work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93324/170373)

Comment: Yes, the embedded {} did not take effect .... within sh -c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we did the following correct method via `sh -c 'grep ... '` with `find -exec` commands. Thanks all!

```shellsession
# find /usr/bin -type f -exec sh -c ' grep -q ''\#'\!/usr/bin/csh'  "$1" && ls -l "$1" ' sh {} \; >scripts_csh_list 2>&1

# head -3  scripts_csh_list                                                                                             
-r-xr-xr-x    1 bin      bin            1191 Sep 06 2007  /usr/bin/which
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of what appears to be unnecessary quoting and escaping in the original. While I don't have any `csh` scripts in `/usr/bin`, I was able to find `bash` scripts and get the `ls` output you appear to want with the following:

```
find /usr/bin -type f -exec grep -q '#!/usr/bin/bash' {} \; -exec ls -l {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

(I verified this by running without the second `-exec`, e.g.,

```
find /usr/bin -type f -exec grep -q '#!/usr/bin/bash' {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

and inspecting the results.)

For a slightly different output listing, you could also do

```
find /usr/bin -type f -exec grep -q '#!/usr/bin/bash' {} \; -ls 2> /dev/null
```

where `find` stats each matching file itself, directly, and returns `ls`-like results.

I piped errors to `/dev/null` simply to make things more readable as I was testing; for similar reasons, I didn't pipe the output to a file.

Note that I am using `bash` as my shell, so wrapping the `grep` expression in single quotes (`'...'`) was sufficient to prevent any interpretation of its contents (not that there is much to worry about, forward slashes (`/`) aren't special for the shell, at least not for bash. If you are using a shell with different quoting rules, YMMV.

As to the command, unless you use the `-o` option, `find` will `AND` together all criteria, so this runs `ls -l` ONLY on regular files (the `type f` you included) that pass the `grep` check. As noted in the comments on your question, `grep -q` likely does what you want, which is simply determine if the file in question (`{}`) matches or not.

EDIT:
As noted in the comments, if the user's shell is `csh`, they will need to escape the `!` in the `grep` expression: `'#\!/usr/bin/bash'` should work.

Comment: The OP is likely using csh where quoting works differently. See [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296147)

Comment: Using `-exec ls -ld {} +` with `+` (and -d for good measure) would avoid running one `ls` per file. With a `grep` with support for `-Z`/`--null` and a `xargs` that supports `-r0`, that could also be done for `grep`, but it doesn't look like the OP's system is a GNU one.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas from the reference you posted it looks like `'#\!/usr/bin/bash'` would suffice.

Comment: Yes, or `\#\!/usr/bin/bash` without the quotes to make it work in both sh-like and csh-like shells.