# understanding bash positional arguments in "find -exec bash..."

Tags: bash, find

I have a file named "testfile"

I launch command `find -name testfile -exec bash -c 'file $0' {} \;`

This command works, but `find -name testfile -exec bash -c 'file $1' {} \;` does not.

I always thought `$0` expanded to command itself and `$1` expanded to first arggument. Isn't it supposed to be that `$0` is `file` command itself and `$1` have to be it's argument and in my example it's the value of `{}`? What i'm missing?

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93324

Comment: And one note: `find` should have the starting path! Like this: `find /path -name filename....`